# Removing old "empty" Datastores that still contain .nvram/.dvsData files/folders

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

I have several old Datastores from which i moved all VMs via Storage vMotion to new Datastores.
Now the VMs themself don't show any link to these old DSs anymore, but if you browse the DSs they still contain .dvsData Folders and .nvram Files.

My google search just showed that the .dvsData Folders contain data used for the distributed Switches and that the .nvram basicly contain the "BIOS". Also that .nvram will be created.

My question is, do i have to migrate these too? or are those just left over? will/are they newly generated with all current data or will something be lost because default settings are used?

On VMware vCenter Server 4.1

EDIT: for anyone intressted here is the [KB-Article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1029786) for acutally removing DSs in 4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are certain no virtual machines are on that datastore then according to [this KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018394) you can safely remove the .dvsData folder.

The [nvRAM files store virtual BIOS information](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_learning_files_in_a_vm.html), which if you have moved the machines you can safely delete these files as well.  Just note that any custom BIOS settings in the guest machines may need to be reconfigured.

Comment: to be honest that's what i thought too, but it's good to have a second opinion before actually deleting something.

Comment: Definitely agreed.  Glad to help.